# I could not manage to play sound on specific event at tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

i want to play a sound when a text changes at spesific area on a webpage which continiously refresh with script.

I want that code to refresh and play a sound when it is not match the text i entered.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Audio Script
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://x
// @match        https://x
// @match        https://x
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    var audio = document.createElement("audio");
    audio.src = "http://y/vuvuzela-trumpet.mp3";

    function reload()
    { location.reload();};

    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("sl-nm")[0].firstChild.attributes[0].nodeValue;
    console.log(x)

    if ( x != "/a/b" ); // text i entered 
    audio.play;

    var interval = Math.random()*5000
    var interval2 = Math.random()*5000
    var gecikme = (interval+interval2)*2.3
    console.log(gecikme/60000)
    var myVar = setInterval(() => reload(), gecikme)


    // Your code here...
})();
```

Comment: "`http://y/vuvuzela-trumpet.mp3`" is not a valid URL, perhaps that is your issue?

Comment: No, i changed links because of privacy because they are on my server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that, if anyone gets same error like me;

```
if ( x != "/a/b" ); // text i entered 
audio.play;
```

Must change like

```
if ( x != "/a/b" ); // text i entered 
    audio.play() ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please don't rely on indentation when using JavaScript - just use brackets to create conditional statements:

```js
(function() {
    'use strict';

    var audio = document.createElement("audio");
    audio.src = "http://y/vuvuzela-trumpet.mp3";

    function reload() {
        location.reload();
    }

    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("sl-nm")[0].firstChild.attributes[0].nodeValue;
    console.log(x);

    if ( x != "/a/b" ) { // text i entered 
        audio.play;
    }

    var interval = Math.random()*5000;
    var interval2 = Math.random()*5000;
    var gecikme = (interval+interval2)*2.3;
    console.log(gecikme/60000);
    var myVar = setInterval(() => reload(), gecikme);


    // Your code here...
})();
```